# Saving results second by second in Python

Tags: python, timer, saving-data

> I am measuring a parameter which is a distance between two objects in a live video. I want to save my results (distance) in a text file "second by second" along with the time. To be more specific I want a text file

**including two columns:**

```
1- Time = [1,2,3,4,5,6,...]

2- Distance = [7,4,8,2,3,1,...]
```

and I need this text file to be updated second by second. I was wondering if someone could help me with that.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you post what code have you tried till now?

Comment: Is there a reason you are writing to a file in realtime?  Could you instead just update your results in memory second by second then write it all to the file at the end?

Answer (score 0):

An example for you, not exactly what you want, but maybe useful:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.6
import time
from datetime import datetime
from pathlib import Path

fname = "a.txt"


def get_distance():
    from random import randint

    return randint(1, 10000)


def main():
    t = 1
    p = Path(fname)
    if not p.exists():
        s = " Time Distance"
        p.write_text(f"{s}\n")
        print(f"``{s}`` appended to {fname}")
    with p.open("a") as f:
        while True:
            d = get_distance()
            line = f"{t:5} {d}"
            f.write(f"{line}\n")
            print(f"``{line}`` appended to {fname}")
            time.sleep(1)
            t += 1


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Output(a.txt):

```
 Time Distance
    1 5772
    2 7654
    3 2918
    4 3980
```